# Programmatically generate 2D pixel graphics

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, 2d, pixel

I just stumbled across [obelisk.js](https://github.com/nosir/obelisk.js/), which is a "JavaScript Engine for Building Isometric Pixel Element with HTML5 Canvas".

See some examples here: [Obelisk.js, Drawing 3D Pixel Art in HTML5 Canvas](http://www.codersgrid.com/2014/03/24/obelisk-js-drawing-3d-pixel-art-in-html5-canvas/)

Is there anything similar (a library or blog post) to this dealing with 2D pixels? I'd like to how it holds up against traditional sprite-based animation.

Comment: Have you thought of using SVG? Have a look at SnapSVG: http://snapsvg.io/

Comment: Are there any examples for programmatically creating 2D pixel art with SnapSVG or svg in general?

Comment: Have a look on CodePen: http://codepen.io/search?q=snapsvg&limit=all&order=popularity&depth=everything&show_forks=false

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but there are only SnapSVG examples in general. None of them seem to be related to this question.